# Mac Storage having buggy behaviour, showing more storage for icloud than what I have

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, storage

My MacBook Pro Apple M2 Darwin Kernel Version 23.3.0 has a bug.

So I have currently a shortage of storage and I tried to see what exactly is taking up my space. However the results were surprising

It says here that the maximum data is taken up by my icloud which amounts to 300GB!!!!
Which is not possible as I only have the free icloud version which has maximum storage of 5GB[image]

I do confirm this as you can see in my second[image]

I have tried to refresh this storage attribute of my mac a lot by opening and closing the settings menu but still behaves the same. Any leads?